# Need Help on C# OracleConnection sql injection

Tags: c#

As I informed earlier I am new to C# and doing some security fix work . Need help for below issue.

Getting sql injection for below piece of code. Here we are getting user id and password from a different configuration file and storing those here in string type variable.

```
this.USER_ID = args[0].ToString();
this.DB_SOURCE = args[1].ToString();
this.DB_LOGIN = args[2].ToString();
this.DB_PASSWORD = args[3].ToString();

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

OracleConnectionStringBuilder connection = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder();

connection.DataSource = this.DB_SOURCE;
connection.UserID = this.DB_LOGIN;
connection.Password = this.DB_PASSWORD;

cmd.Connection = new OracleConnection(connection.ConnectionString);

cmd.Connection.Open();`
```

I tired to change it to below way to avoid sql injection. But it seems this piece of code is not working. I tried to print the variable that we are passing but it seems its not getting copied. Could someone tell me if I an doing anything wrong here

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

OracleConnectionStringBuilder connection = new 
OracleConnectionStringBuilder("Data Source = this.DB_SOURCE;User ID = this.DB_LOGIN;Password = this.DB_PASSWORD;");

EventLog.WriteEntry(sSource, " Data Source:" + connection.Data Source, EventLogEntryType.Information); // getting output : Data Source:this.DB_SOURCE

EventLog.WriteEntry(sSource, "User id:" + connection.UserID, EventLogEntryType.Information); // getting output: User id:this.DB_LOGIN

EventLog.WriteEntry(sSource, "Password:" + connection.Password, EventLogEntryType.Information); // getting output: Password:this.DB_PASSWORD

cmd.Connection = new OracleConnection(connection.ConnectionString);`
```

Comment: Are your connections dependent on user input - which usually means you have, and users can connect to, multiple databases? If not, then look into setting these in secure configuration options (no user input).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response, yes this connection is dependent on user input and all the connection credential are coming from a secure configuration file.

Comment: *I am new to C# and doing some security fix work* - not wishing to appear rude, but I don't think your current tasking is a great fit for your experience. This question arose from an incredibly trivial and highly fundamental lack of understanding of how strings work in C#; I don't think you yet possess the necessary C# skills to identify and carry out security critical work. You don't even appear to know what SQL Injection is, because while the posted code may contain the potential for connection string alteration, it doesn't contain any SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

The way you are building your connection string then it is pure text.  At the moment you have this

```
OracleConnectionStringBuilder("Data Source = this.DB_SOURCE;User ID = this.DB_LOGIN;Password = this.DB_PASSWORD;");
```

So you are taking the using the string of "this.DB_SOURCE" as the data source.  You are NOT taking the value out of this variable as you expect.  If you change this string to "AnyOldRubbish" then it would work in the same way that you have today.

If you can use **C# version 6.0** or higher (.Net Framework 4.6 or above) then one way is to use string interpolation like this.

```
OracleConnectionStringBuilder($"Data Source = {this.DB_SOURCE};User ID = {this.DB_LOGIN};Password = {this.DB_PASSWORD};");
```

The $ sign at the front of the string says use string interpolation, and then the brackets are used to define which values should be treated as variables within the string and then extract the value from them.

More details on String interpolation can be found here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

If you are on an **older C# version**, then you can simply concatenate the strings

```
OracleConnectionStringBuilder("Data Source = " + this.DB_SOURCE + ";User ID = " + this.DB_LOGIN  + ";Password = " + this.DB_PASSWORD + ";");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response I tried this way also but getting error. seems its doesn't recognize $ sign. getting error like "Unexpected character '$'". updated code below way ` OracleConnectionStringBuilder connection = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder($"Data Source = {this.DB_SOURCE};User ID = {this.DB_LOGIN};Password = {this.DB_PASSWORD};"); `

Comment: @sid String interpolation only works with C# 6 and above.  If you are targeting an older version, then you just need to concatenate the strings.  I have updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes i did move to the newer version and tried this code. its working but I am still getting sql injection error. how to avoid that sql injection here. how can we modify this code to avoid sql injection? Please suggest.